# Save contents of iFrame to html file?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am building a rich text editor using JavaScript and an editable iFrame, and I am wondering how I can use php to save the contents of the iframe to an html file.

Comment: Why would you want to save the contents of an iframe to an html file? file_get_contents will do what you need. Also accept some of your previous answers.

Comment: Yup. If you asked for help here and people responded. At least accept some answers.

Answer (score 1):

WARNING The link http://simple.procoding.net/2008.....  provided by iWantSimpleLife generates a Javascript Obfuscation alert. That site may be infected.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't an iframe basically a page you're retrieving ?

If so, then file_get_contents ( http://php.net/manual/fr/function.file-get-contents.php ) should do the trick.

Comment: In this case, no. All the content in the RTE is added at runtime; the frame source is either an empty file, or `about:blank`.

Comment: Well, then, if it's runtime, php shouldn't be able to retrieve anything, should it ?
Except if you decide to make like a temp file with JS, or something like that ?

Comment: Exactly. RTEs involve a bunch of Javascript artifice, and sure enough, the answer to this question is "more Javascript artifice".

Answer (score 0):

First, With Javascript copy the contents of the Html text of the iframe and then paste them to text in a textarea.
Then submit the text area contents to PHP script that safe it in a text file with html extension on your webserver.

Recall file system manual of PHP
http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php

Answer (score -2):

Use javascript to get the content.  http://simple.procoding.net/2008/03/21/how-to-access-iframe-in-jquery/

This took me about 5 minutes to Google.